# Validating a credit card

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, validation, finance

I recently created an extension which detects the type of credit card based on the numbers entered in and formats it. I am using Luhn Algorithm for validating credit card numbers and I am using jQuery masking for formatting the credit card numbers (for reference: jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min).

You can play with the demo [here](http://frontendprojects.com/monkdetect/).

How can I make this extensive? What should I be thinking about and what might not be so good in my current code?

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // hiding the status as the user focuses on the credit card input field
    $('.card input').bind('focus', function() {
        $("#ccard_number").unmask();//unmasking the text field as user starts typing
        $('.card .status').hide();
    });

    // showing the status when the user tabs or clicks away from the credit card input field
    $('.card input').bind('blur', function() {
        $('.card .status').show();

    });

    // checking input value entered using jquery.cardchecker
    $('.card input').cardchecker({
        callback: function(result) {

            var status = (result.validLen && result.validLuhn) ? 'valid' : 'invalid',
                message = '',
                types = '',
                i;

            // Getting the names of all accepted card types.
            for (i in result.option.types) {
                types += result.option.types[i].name + ", ";
            }
            types = types.substring(0, types.length-2);

            // Set the status message
            if (result.len < 1) {
                message = 'Please enter a credit card number.';
            } else if (!result.cardClass) {
                message = 'We accept the following card types: ' + types + '.';
            } else if (!result.validLen) {
                message = 'It appears to be wrong number of digit. Please check that this number matches your "' + result.cardName + '" card';
            } else if (!result.validLuhn) {
                message = 'Did you mistype a digit as this number matches your "' + result.cardName + '" card ';
            } else {
                message = 'It looks like a valid ' + result.cardName + '.';
                if ( result.validLen ) {
                    if ( result.cardName === 'Visa' ) { //if the card is Visa
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("9999-9999-9999-9?999");
                    }
                    if ( result.cardName === 'American Express' ) { //if the card is American Express
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("999-999999-999999");
                    }
                    if ( result.cardName === 'MasterCard' ) { //if the card is MasterCard
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999");
                    }
                    if ( result.cardName === 'Discover' ) { //if the card is Discover
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999");
                    }
                    if ( result.cardName === 'JCB' ) { //if the card is JCB
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999");
                    }
                    if ( result.cardName === 'Diners Club' ) { //if the card is Diners Club
                        $("#ccard_number").mask("999-999999-99999");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Show credit card icon
            $('.card .card_icon').removeClass().addClass('card_icon ' + result.cardClass);

            // Show status message
            $('.card .status').removeClass('invalid valid').addClass(status).children('.status_message').text(message);

        }
    });
});

/*
 * function for validating and formatting credit cards
 */
(function($, window, document) {
    var defaultvalue;

    // Plugin Core
    $.cardchecker = function(option) {
        var ccard = defaultvalue.types || [],
            num = (typeof option === "string") ? option : option.num,
            len = num.length,
            type,
            validLen = false,
            validLuhn = false;

        // Get matched type based on credit card number
        $.each(ccard, function(index, card) {
            if (card.checkType(num)) {
                type = index;
                return false;
            }
        });

        // If number, ccard, and a matched type
        if (num && ccard && ccard[type]) {
            // Check card length
            validLen = ccard[type].checkLength(len);

            // Check Luhn Algorithm
            validLuhn = defaultvalue.checkLuhn(num);
        }

        return {
            type: type,
            validLen: validLen,
            validLuhn: validLuhn
        };
    };

    // Plugin Helper
    $.fn.cardchecker = function(option) {
        // Allow for just a callback to be provided or extend method that merges the contents of two or more objects, storing the result in the first object.
        if (option && $.isFunction(option)) {
            var _option = $({}, defaultvalue);
            _option.callback = option;
            option = _option;
        } else {
            option = $.extend({}, defaultvalue, option);
        }

        // Fire on keyup
        return this.bind('keyup', function() {
            var ccard = option.types || {},
                num = this.value.replace(/\D+/g, ''), // strip all non-digits
                name = '',
                className = '',

            // Check card
            check = $.cardchecker({
                num: num
            });

            // Assign className based on matched type
            if (typeof check.type === "number") {
                name = ccard[check.type].name;
                className = ccard[check.type].className;
            }

            // Invoke callback
            option.callback.call(this, {
                num: num,
                len: num.length,
                cardName: name,
                cardClass: className,
                validLen: check.validLen,
                validLuhn: check.validLuhn,
                option: option
            });

        });
    };

    // Plugin Options
    defaultvalue = $.fn.cardchecker.option = {
        checkLuhn: function(num) {
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm
            var len = num.length,
            total = 0,
            i;
            if (!num || !len) {
                return false;
            }
            num = num.split('').reverse();
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                num[i] = window.parseInt(num[i], 10);
                total += i % 2 ? 2 * num[i] - (num[i] > 4 ? 9 : 0) : num[i];
            }
            return total % 10 === 0;
        },
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bank_Identification_Numbers
        types: [
            {
                name: 'Visa',
                className: 'visa',
                checkType: function(num) { return num.charAt(0) === '4'; },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 13 || len === 16; }
            },
            {
                name: 'American Express',
                className: 'amex',
                checkType: function(num) { return num.substr(0, 2) === '34' || num.substr(0, 2) === '37'; },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 15; }
            },
            {
                name: 'MasterCard',
                className: 'mastercard',
                checkType: function(num) {
                    if (num.charAt(0) === '5') {
                        return num.charAt(1) >= 1 && num.charAt(1) <= 5;
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 16; }
            },
            {
                name: 'Discover',
                className: 'discover',
                checkType:  function(num) {
                    if (num.charAt(0) === '6') {
                        return num.substr(0, 2) === '65' || num.substr(0, 4) === '6011' || num.substr(0, 3) === '644' || (num.substr(0, 1) === '6' && parseInt(num, 10) >= '622126' && parseInt(num, 10) <= '622925');
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 16; }
            },
            {
                name: 'JCB',
                className: 'jcb',
                checkType:  function(num) { return num.substr(0, 2) === '35'; },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 16; }
            },
            {
                name: 'Diners Club',
                className: 'diners',
                checkType:  function(num) { return num.substr(0, 2) === '36' || num.substr(0, 2) === '38'; },
                checkLength: function(len) { return len === 14; }
            }
        ],
        callback: $.noop
    };

})(jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? http://paweldecowski.github.com/jQuery-CreditCardValidator/

Comment: yes, I am aware about this. I want to extend it by formatting the credit card numbers.

Comment: The first thing that popped into my head in regards to "extending" it: localization. What if you want other messages? What if you want multiple languages?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is you could remove many lines of code by using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
name: 'Visa',
    className: 'visa',
    checkPattern: /^4\d{12}\d{3}?$/
```

This means:

- / beginning of the search pattern, required by JavaScript.
- ^ don't match if there's anything before this pattern.
- 4 literal number 4
- \d{12} exactly 12 digits
- \d{3}? optionally followed by another 3 digits
- $ don't match if there's anything after this pattern.
- / end of the search pattern, required by JavaScript.

Using regular expressions would allow you to replace `checkLength` and `checkType` with a single method.

**Edit:** cleaned up regex, thanks to @Schism.

Comment: `\d` exists, so why not use it instead of `[0-9]`? The capturing group is also not needed. The regex could be written as `^4\d{12}\d{3}?$`. Plus, I question using a string when Javascript has built-in regex support; something like `checkPattern: /^4\d{12}\d{3}?$/` might be nicer.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know THAT much regex stuff. :)